# Rails way to detect mobile device?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile

Is there a "rails way" to detect whether the user is using a mobile device? What I mean is a method I can use in erb, something like this:

```
<% if mobile? %>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it that way by defining a function like below:

```
def mobile_device?
  if session[:mobile_param]
    session[:mobile_param] == "1"
  else
    request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
  end
end
```

Or you can use gems to detect mobile devices like

- https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette
- https://github.com/shenoudab/active_device

Comment: Looks like active_device is inactive.

Comment: could you please update the answer to a mix of yours and the one below as browser gem is more used as shown in https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/browser

Comment: how to test it, I mean how do I tell respect that I want to run it now as mobile devise?

Comment: agent sniffing is an pretty imperfect way to do this, and whatever implementation you choose to sniff, it gets less accurate over time

Answer (score 22):

Use [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser) gem. You are able to detect the browser by the custom user_agent.

Comment: Do you know if Google Chrome's mobile browser emulator would detect `browser.mobile?` with that gem?

Comment: `browser` is nice but requires > ruby 2. if you're stuck on 1.9.3 (like me) check out https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette

Comment: @JoeMorano it does work in Chrome's emulator for me.

Comment: `browser` appears to still be maintained in 2020 and has only increased in usage over time.

Answer (score 20):

In `application_helper.rb`:

```
def device
  agent = request.user_agent
  return "tablet" if agent =~ /(tablet|ipad)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i
  return "mobile" if agent =~ /Mobile/
  return "desktop"
end
```

Then you can use it in your views:

```
<% if device == "mobile" %>
  Show something for mobile users.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest checking out device_detector, which is quite fast and easy to deploy. You just have to pass user_agent string to it, which can be done using request.user_agent for Rails 5:

```
@user_agent = request.user_agent

@client = DeviceDetector.new(@user_agent)

@client.device_type
```

Note: Device types can be one of the following: desktop, smartphone, tablet, console, portable media player, tv, car browser, camera

https://github.com/podigee/device_detector

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this too by simply [including](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kantY664KOw)     `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` on the `application.html.erb` header tag

As long as your site is responsive (e.g. using Bootstrap), you should be fine.

Comment: The question seeks to check if the user agent is a mobile device. Your answer aims to enable a responsive behavior, which is pretty different from the question intention.