# write different HTML for ipad in index.html file only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, railscasts

I have a rails site running done using the bootstrap. There's a mobile and tablet site for the same. Mobile and tablet site have completely same feature apart from having a slightly different index page.

I have used [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices) to load the app on the mobile device.

Is it possible to have another url like used in the article for tablets.

For eg for mobile, `localhost:3000/pages/home?mobile=0`

This is what can be used. Can we use something like this for tablets?

Like we write media queries for CSS, Is it possible that I write different HTML in mobile.html file and load that chunk of code for tabs, As I need a small change to the index page only.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

> It has to be rails centric

You'll want to use `request.user_agent`:

```
if request.user_agent =~ /android|blackberry|iphone|ipad|ipod|iemobile|mobile|webos/i
 ## mobile
else
 ## not mobile
end
```

So you could do something like this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def mobile?
      request.user_agent =~ /android|blackberry|iphone|ipad|ipod|iemobile|mobile|webos/i
   end
   helper_method :mobile?
end

#app/views/pages/home.html.erb
<%= render "small_change" if mobile? %>
```

--

Some refs:

- [Rails 3 detect request coming from mobile clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069054/rails-3-detect-request-coming-from-mobile-clients)
- [Rails way to detect mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068869/rails-way-to-detect-mobile-device)

---

**Update**

The above allows you to call the `mobile?` method in any view you need.

Because it's in the application controller, it has access to the `request` object (otherwise you'd have to pass it to the action each time).

So when you asked:

> So where should I put that code in mobile's index.html. As I don't want to add other files

... there is no "mobile" index.html.erb. You can call the `mobile?` method in any view you need:

```
#app/views/pages/home.html.erb
<% if mobile? %>
   .... do something here.
<% end %>
```

Comment: that's how I am doing it. But as I said for iPad, I need a slight change in code for index page. Other pages are similar. So where should I put that code in mobile's index.html. As I don't want to add other files

Comment: The code is pretty self explanatory -- you create a `mobile?` helper method *in the controller* (so it has access to `request` object). You can then call `mobile?` in any view you want.

Comment: as I said I don't want to call another view as only slight change is there .
 I mean I have desktop view and mobile view. I don't want to create views for desktops all over as everything is almost same apart from the change in the index page

Comment: Dude read the freaking answer. There is NO VIEW involved in what I recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Less is more.  Keep it simple. I propose a simple jquery/html/css solution.  Have one and only one file. Modify the different areas of the html file via unique class names.  In this case I have desktop coding or mobile coding.  In your case you can split it up as you see fit, obviously by modifying the if statement shown below.

In html:

```
 <main id="top_main"  class="website_desktop">desktop content goes here.</main>
```

or

```
<main  id="top_mobile" class="website_mobile">mobile content goes here.</main>
```

In script:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // display stuff for mobile
    jQuery("#top_main").css("display", "none");
    jQuery("#top_mobile").css("display", "block");
}else {
    // hide all stuff for mobile, display desktop
    jQuery("#top_mobile").css("display", "none");
    jQuery("#top_main").css("display", "block");
}
```

ID's are used for script, classes are used for different CSS controls (in my example, mobile vs desktop)

Comment: Thanks, but have everything set up completely using that rails cast. Where I have different views(html), css and js for desktops and mobiles. All I need is a small change in html for tablet and I don't wanna have multiple files again for the tabs.

This will again be time consuming I think

Comment: Perhaps I was too subtle. I used desktop vs mobile as an EXAMPLE.  In your case, the `if` statement would be tablet or not tablet.  Adjust ID and class names accordingly.   But yeah, I can see where that would be a control logic shift (crappy band aid only), and you want to be consistent with Rails everywhere.

Comment: exactly. It has to be rails centric

Comment: This would force the browser to load a mobile and desktop site when only using one. Why take the browser resources to load all the mobile assets if you're not going to use them?